# В чем разница между паттерном Стратегия и Состояние?

Tags: c#, unity3d, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучаю сейчас программирование на Unity. 3 дня ломаю голову над вопросом в чем отличие паттерна **Стратегия(Strategy) от Состояния(State)**. Смотря через призму Unity я совсем не понимаю в чем разница, и в какой ситуации какой паттерн выгоднее реализовывать. Информации в интернете не так уж много по этой теме, по крайней мере я не нашел что искал. Можете бить ссаными тряпками, мол плохо гуглил, только дайте ответ, пожалуйста. У меня ощущение, что я упустил важную деталь и ответ где-то близко, но из-за небольшого опыта мне сложно понять. Для тех кто может объяснить преложил свою реализацию этих паттернов, как я их вижу. Скорее всего проблема в реализации и я из-за этого не могу понять суть. Код максимально урезан для удобочитаемости. **[Состояние](https://gist.github.com/Aitix/b1474d81db8e06f9d4d21ea280373461) [Стратегия](https://gist.github.com/Aitix/009f85e08f0edebc4a9b1c76c5d40995)**.

Comment: один шаблон позволяет хранить состояние, а второй изменять поведение. Тут скорее вопрос - что у них вообще общего?

Comment: Стратегия - это когда по отдельным классам раскидывают алгоритмы. Например, написать разные алгоримы сортировки в разных классах и подменять один класс другим в вашем коде. То есть стратегия определяет какой то класс алгоритмов.
Состояние - это когда по классам раскидывают разные варианты состояний. Ментально это можно представить как города, соединенные дорогами. Вы сейчас в городе А (ваше состояние А), вы можете поехать в город Б (получить новое состояние Б из состояния А). А и Б тут будут состояниями, а вид транспорта, на котором вы можете доехать (машина, автобус, велик) - стратегией.

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/strategy и https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/state

Comment: п.с. ссылок с кодом сюда не надо кидать. Кидайте сам код, его минимальный вариант -  см [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Не увлекатесь слишком заучиванием *названий* паттернов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо тебе показалось, что Стратегия, это как Состояние, которое мы не меняем и в принципе так и есть, в единицу времени мы работаем с всего одной реализацией из многих под общей абстракцией, одна и та-же концепция. На тему `что у них вообще общего?` от @Grundy.

Даже стратегия-фасад, когда одна стратегия это набор из нескольких не уникальна, можно написать и состояние-фасад, хоть это и вряд-ли имеет смысл. Да, самое сложное состояние `final-state-mashine` ни с какой стратегий не сравнить, но тогда у новичка может возникнуть вопрос, а нахрена эта стратегия ваще нужна?

---

Все просто.

Когда мы шарим картинку с текстом в социалку на выбор у каждой из которых собственная библиотека, используется стратегия. Или когда одна и та-же игра запускается под `DerictX`, `OpenGL` или другим графическим api, она выбирает стратегию для рендера и это может не ограничиваться всего одним классом, речь может быть о целых фреймворках и о легкой смены с одной стратегии на другую в реальном времени не может быть и речи, множество сущьностей из-за выбранной стратегии проинициализировались особым способом и нужно начинать весь процесс с начала. Или квесты в играх, их условия выполнения это стратегия `принеси N(количество), I(предмет)`, `убей N, M(монстр)`, фасад из нескольких разом или фасад одно из двух, тоже самое касается условий провала квеста `за T(время)`, `нанести урон M`(не трогать), это буквально одни и те-же стратегии, которые просто в разных полях выполнение/провал.

Когда юнит в рпг или стратегии(жанр) постоянно скачет от одного к другому и обратно: стоит/бежит/атакует/умирает то он меняет состояния. Когда мы настраиваем анимацию в окне `Animator`, это редактор состояний с регламентированными переходами, тот самый вышеупомянутый `final-state-mashine`.

---

Концепт похожий, но из-за условий использывания они разные. Состояние которое должно постоянно меняться, может иметь крайне короткою абстракцию, бывает обхожусь всего `Enter()` и `Exit()`. В стратегиях иные реализации вовсе не инициализируются, существует всего лишь одна и у этих реализаций нет и не может быть никаких связей друг с другом, как например переходов в `Animator`. И как ты уже мог догадаться, по примеру с графическим api, абстракция может быть довольно мудренной, подобную абстракцию состояния трудно даже представить.